# How do I vectorise this in numpy using `np.choose` or `np.take` or similar?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to vectorise the following `do_permutation` function. I want to remove the loop in python and use numpy methods instead.

```
import numpy as np

def do_permutation(indices):
    perm = np.zeros(len(indices), dtype='int32')
    for i, o in enumerate(indices):
        perm[o] = i
    return perm

assert list(do_permutation([3, 2, 4, 1, 0])) == [4, 3, 1, 0, 2]
```

Comment: My initial thoughts were `np.choose` and `np.take`.

Comment: Looks like [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to me: `assert list(np.argsort([3, 2, 4, 1, 0])) == [4, 3, 1, 0, 2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution is

```
do_perm = np.argsort
```

However, this solution is `O(N log N)`. For sufficiently long indices which are actually permutations of a range from zero to N, an `O(N)` solution is worthwhile. In that case, use direct ordering:

```
def do_perm(indices):
    perm = np.empty_like(indices)
    perm[indices] = np.arange(len(indices))
    return perm
```

The last line can also be written as

```
np.put(perm, indices, np.arange(indices.size))
```

Using [`np.put`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) allows you to handle unraveled `indices` transparently.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to a slice of the array indexed with the given indices.

```py
def do_permutation(indices):
    N = len(indices);
    perm = np.zeros(N, dtype='int32')
    perm[indices] = np.arange(N)
    return perm
```